# How to stop javascript code being broken when going into visual editor

Tags: javascript, visual-editor

so I already had to make my code uglier than it needed to be, because whenever I tried to do && wordpress decided I wanted &amp, and now I am finding that when I go into visual view any javascript defined on that page breaks.

For example the code I have now (which works):

```
<script>
function checkCosts() {
var date = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value;
var roomtype = document.getElementsByName("roomtype")[0].value;
var night = document.getElementsByName("night")[0].value;
var room = document.getElementsByName("room")[0].value;
var month = date.substring(0, 2);
var year = date.substring(8, 10);
var day = date.substring(4, 6);
var time = month.concat(year);
var fulldate = parseInt(day.concat(time));
var inttime = parseInt(time);
//=================================
//Date Range 1
//Check earliest date
if (inttime >= 415) {
    //Check latest date
    if (inttime <= 915) {
        //Classic Roomtype
        if (roomtype == "Classic") {
            //Nights Double
            if (room = "Double") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,480";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,450";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,415";
                }
            }
            //Nights Single
            if (room = "Single") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,575";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,510";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,440";
                }
            }
        }
        //End
        //Luxury Roomtype
        if (roomtype == "Luxury") {
            //Nights
            if (room = "Double") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,620";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,580";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,535";
                }
            }
            //Nights Single
            if (room = "Single") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,830";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,760";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,685";
                }
            }
        }
        //End
        //Suite Roomtype
        if (roomtype == "Suite") {
            //Nights
            if (room = "Double") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,815";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,770";
                }
            }
            //Nights Single
            if (room = "Single") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,300";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,235";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,145";
                }
            }
        }
        //End
    }
}
 //=================================
        //Date Range 2
        //Check earliest date
            //Check latest date

                //Classic Roomtype
                if (roomtype == "Classic") {
                    //Nights Double
                    if (room = "Double") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,795";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,745";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,700";
                        }
                    }
                    //Nights Single
                    if (room = "Single") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,185";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,100";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,015";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //End
                //Luxury Roomtype
                if (roomtype == "Luxury") {
                    //Nights
                    if (room = "Double") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,960";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,905";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";
                        }
                    }
                    //Nights Single
                    if (room = "Single") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,515";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,425";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,320";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //End
                //Suite Roomtype
                if (roomtype == "Suite") {
                    //Nights
                    if (room = "Double") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,815";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,770";
                        }
                    }
                    //Nights Single
                    if (room = "Single") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "4,505";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "4,375";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "4,245";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //End
            }
}
</script>
```

But as soon as I go into visual editor (which the person I am designing this site for will undoubtedly do) the code becomes

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
function checkCosts() {
var date = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value;
var roomtype = document.getElementsByName("roomtype")[0].value;
var night = document.getElementsByName("night")[0].value;
var room = document.getElementsByName("room")[0].value;
var month = date.substring(0, 2);
var year = date.substring(8, 10);
var day = date.substring(4, 6);
var time = month.concat(year);
var fulldate = parseInt(day.concat(time));
var inttime = parseInt(time);
//=================================
//Date Range 1
//Check earliest date
if (inttime >= 415) {
    //Check latest date
    if (inttime <= 915) {
        //Classic Roomtype
        if (roomtype == "Classic") {
            //Nights Double
            if (room = "Double") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,480";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,450";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,415";
                }
            }
            //Nights Single
            if (room = "Single") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,575";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,510";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,440";
                }
            }
        }
        //End
        //Luxury Roomtype
        if (roomtype == "Luxury") {
            //Nights
            if (room = "Double") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,620";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,580";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,535";
                }
            }
            //Nights Single
            if (room = "Single") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,830";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,760";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "2,685";
                }
            }
        }
        //End
        //Suite Roomtype
        if (roomtype == "Suite") {
            //Nights
            if (room = "Double") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,815";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,770";
                }
            }
            //Nights Single
            if (room = "Single") {
                if (night == "3") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,300";
                }
                if (night == "5") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,235";
                }
                if (night == "7") {
                    document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,145";
                }
            }
        }
        //End
    }
}
 //=================================
        //Date Range 2
        //Check earliest date
            //Check latest date

                //Classic Roomtype
                if (roomtype == "Classic") {
                    //Nights Double
                    if (room = "Double") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,795";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,745";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,700";
                        }
                    }
                    //Nights Single
                    if (room = "Single") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,185";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,100";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,015";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //End
                //Luxury Roomtype
                if (roomtype == "Luxury") {
                    //Nights
                    if (room = "Double") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,960";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,905";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";
                        }
                    }
                    //Nights Single
                    if (room = "Single") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,515";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,425";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "3,320";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //End
                //Suite Roomtype
                if (roomtype == "Suite") {
                    //Nights
                    if (room = "Double") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,860";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,815";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,770";
                        }
                    }
                    //Nights Single
                    if (room = "Single") {
                        if (night == "3") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "4,505";
                        }
                        if (night == "5") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "4,375";
                        }
                        if (night == "7") {
                            document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "4,245";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //End
            }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Which doesn't work. This happens for ANY javascript, no matter how simple or complex that is on a page.

Is there any way to stop this, without having to teach the person I am making this for how to deal with HTML, just so they can edit a few things

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to stop this

Don't have JavaScript in your editor. It's dirty and difficult to maintain (as you've found out).

Instead, you could:

1. Use a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)
2. [Use custom fields](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336) (post meta)
3. Use conditional code in your `functions.php`

For 3), as an example:

```
function wpse_202946_script() {
    if ( is_page( 'id_or_title_or_slug' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'my-theme-script-name',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/script.js',
            null, // Dependencies
            null, // Version
            true  // In footer
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_202946_script' );
```

Comment: Not possible. The script has information which needs to be edited every now and again, and is similar but different, on every page.

For example
     if (night == "7") {document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "1,415";}

May be 1,415 on page 1 but on page 2 be 1,700

Comment: Then use custom fields to set the values you need, and generate the actual code inline in a template file.